# Why does this java code compile

Tags: java, syntax, compiler-errors

I came across this code

```
public class Main {
    static int someint;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        someint = -0;
        print();
    }

    private static int print()
    {
        System.out.println(someint);
        return someint;
    }

}
```

This prints -0 when i run it

I was just curios as to how -0 is a legal integer value

Comment: i don't think you can compile this. you need to enclose `someint = -0;` into curly braces

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: The code as-is will never compile since `someint = -0` must be inside a code block between curly braces `{ }`.

Comment: I forgot the braces when writing the question

Comment: Could you fix the code in your question then?

Comment: What JDK/JRE are you using?

Comment: Your amended code compiles and prints `0`. What JRE are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest JRE/JDK JRE7u21

Comment: So, everybody go and download latest version, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [JLS #15.15.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.4) explicitly says that:

> For integer values, negation is the same as subtraction from zero.

so `int i = -0;` is equivalent to `int i = 0 - 0;` which is equivalent to `int i = 0;`.

Note that it is not the case for floating-point values:

> For floating-point values, negation is not the same as subtraction from zero, because if x is +0.0, then 0.0-x is +0.0, but -x is -0.0.

**So your code MUST print `0` to be compliant with the language.**

Answer (score 6):

Because "-" is a monadic negate operator and works on all numbers including `0` even though it does not affect `0` at all.

See [BNF](http://cui.unige.ch/isi/bnf/JAVA/AJAVA.html) rules for Java:

```
numeric_expression  = 
 (  (  "-" 
 /  "++" 
 /  "--"  ) 
expression ) ...
```

Interestingly `-0.0` is **not** the same number as `0.0`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - I think it answers the question the OP intended to ask.

Answer (score 0):

minus 0 is lust like 0, and the compiler assume someint = 0

Answer (score 0):

Probably you mean something like this:

```
private int someint;

private int print()
{
    someint = -0;
    System.out.println(someint);
    return someint;
}
```

Why this should not be compiled? Unary operation `-` is valid for all numeric constants. For value `0` it doesn't change its sign.

What about your output - it isn't reproducable under last version of JVM (Java 1.7_17). It prints out just `0`.

Comment: @System.Object May be the version you use is buggy?